# Как реализовать задачу с указателями?

Tags: c++

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой код

```
#include <iostream>`

using namespace std;
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    int n;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int resualt = 0;
    cout << "Введите n" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Исходная матрица" << endl;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "(";
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
            cout << n;
        cout << ")" << endl;

    }
    cout << "Матрица с нулями" << endl;
    resualt = n + 1;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "(";
        int resualt2 = n;
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            if (i == 0)  {
                resualt = resualt - 1;
                cout << resualt;
            }
         
            if (i > 0) {
                if (i > j) {
                    cout << 0;
                }
                else { 
                    cout << resualt2;
                    resualt2 = resualt2 - 1;
                

                }
                
            }
        }

        cout << ')' << endl;
    }
}
```

Как реализовать программу с указателями? (Ввод с клавиатуры)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

вообще-то от вас требовалось не на экран вывести картинку, а сформировать двумерный массив целых чисел, ячейки которого будут заполнены в соответствии с приведённой картинкой

алгоритм:

1. сформировать двумерный массив (массив строк)
2. пройтись по всем строкам и заполнить их в соответствии с указанным в задаче правилом

вот в этом случае вам и понадобятся указатели

начните с

```
int** matrix = nullptr;
```